# Django 1.6 Query Math Incorrect

Tags: django

No sure why, but the `context['user_activity_percentage']` is showing 0 when it should be showing 25. This is because `context['user_activity']` is 1 and it is int(1/4 * 100) = 25. I verified this in the manage.py shell_plus.  Why is it showing 0 instead of 25?

```
    context['user_activity'] = CommunityProfile.list_all_users.date_search(
            date1, date2, column="last_activity").count()
    context['user_activity_percentage'] = int(context['user_activity']/
            CommunityProfile.objects.count() * 100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Python 2.x, `1/4` is `0`, not `0.25`:

```
>>> 1 / 4
0
```

If you want to get `0.25`, convert one of the value to `float`:

```
>>> float(1) / 4
0.25
```

This behavior is different from Python 3.x's ([PEP-238: True division](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)). If you want `/` works like Python 3.x, do the following:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 1 / 4
0.25
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot I imported `from __future__ import division` into the shell....in case anyone else would like an alternative.